# iOS7 and Apple Watch

Tags: ios, ios7, watchkit, apple-watch

I have a app with the minimum iOS target iOS7.

I am considering in add some extra features with the apple watch. Theres is any option to maintain the iOS7 as the minimum target and still add support for apple watch if the app is running on a iOS 8? Something like the extensions/widgets of the iOS8.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set your deployment target to iOS7.x and make sure you build against iOS8.2 SDK. You will need to set the frameworks as `optional` (weak linking) in your build settings and perform run time checks to ensure you don't attempt anything with them on an iOS7.x device.

Optional frameworks will resolve as `nil` in an app where the framework is not linked.

Comment: Transis for the help. Just one doubt, how can i validate the imports?

Comment: What do you mean by validate the imports?

Comment: for example, i have a class that is only compatible with iOS8. So when the app is running i validate if the class exist "if ([Example class])". The import should be added (#import Example.h), it will not give me a error when i am running in the iOS7, since the class is not available?

Comment: It will still compile as you will be building against the 8.x SDK, but when the app runs on your minimum deployment targets, any classes that are part of frameworks that aren't linked will just be considered nil, and sending messages to nil in Objective-c is completely valid. In a lot of scenarios, you won't even need to add if ([Example class]), because it will resolve to nil anyway. Just make sure you don't send any selectors to objects that don't respond to them, e.g. when a new API was added to an existing framework in both iOS7 and 8. Hope this helps.

Comment: Problem is that the embedded library (for the watchApp) can't be weak linked. So it's not gonna work. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible by weak linking WatchKit and performing runtime checks if required classes are available. Check this out on [Raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/42591/supporting-multiple-ios-versions-and-devices).

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's WatchKit or any other new API. Weaklinking + runtime checks would allow OP to implement the WatchKit API, while keeping iOS7 as the base version.

Comment: @Andrew I stand corrected, you're right.  I assumed the `respondsToSelector` would fail.  Good call.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the only thing I had to do was creating the extension with Objective-C (Swift is not allowed on some iOS versions) and downgrading the Extension app target version to 8.2 instead of 8.3.