# How to use AdMob only if Deployment target is greater than 6.0?

Tags: ios, admob

I want my app to support iOS 5.0. But Admob has a prerequisite that the deployment target is at least 6.0.

Is there a way to compile my app so that Admob is used only for devices running iOS >= 6.0 ?

I ask because people have done something similar with apple watch so they can support lower deployment targets: [iOS7 and Apple Watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509935/ios7-and-apple-watch)

Answer (score 2):

```
/*
 *  System Versioning Preprocessor Macros
 */ 

#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v)              ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)     ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)
```

Then use like this

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0")) {
    //do admob stuff
}
else {
   //don't do admob stuff
}
```

Also link optional framework which are not available in ios < 6.0

P.S. The macros is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5337804/468724)